# TFS move to a more powerful machine

Tags: team-foundation-server

We need to move TFS (basic source control only configuration) to a brand new - more powerful - machine. I found several articles on the subject but I cannot figure out what's the best approach for my scenario. Currently I have only installed Windows Server 2008 R2 as in the original machine.

Here are the options so far:

1) [Move Team Foundation Server from One Hardware Configuration to Another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx)

2) [Move a Team Project Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936138.aspx)

3) [TFS 2010 Power Tools Backup and Restore](http://myalmblog.com/2010/09/12/tfs-2010-power-tools-tfs-backup-and-restore-hands-on-lab/)

What I like most is 3) but I was discouraged from this: [TFS Power Tools backup plan is not used to backup one TFS DBs and restore them to another TFS DBs](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfspowertools/thread/1d730cff-23fb-416b-87b2-73a349664c6e/)

What is the most straightforward way to accomplish my task and put the new machine at work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for option 1. Your scenario is exactly where this article is written for.

Option 2 is used when you want to move a Team Project Collection from one TFS instance to another instance.

Option 3 is for Disaster Recovery.

Comment: What's the difference between a disaster recovery and moving to a new machine?

Comment: You can proably use disaster recovery for moving to another machine, but disaster recovery is more meant to create a recursive backup plan, so you always have the data in TFS if a database gets unavailable due to whatever reason. When you look to option 1, it takes into account everything to get the environment up and running again, including Reporting and SharePoint. When you leave that out there is not much more left than just install TFS on the server and then restore a database. Because you are moving to a new machine with a new name there are some additional steps that are also described.

Comment: Thanks Ewald, btw we don't use Reporting and Sharepoint, only basic source control and work items. Users are defined only on the server machine, this is another interesting part of the job: what would happen when on the new machine I will redefine the users (same usernames and passwords)?

Comment: Users are stored with their SIDs on the server IIRC. Moving your server to a new workgroup environment, probably will give you new users (although the name is the same)